# Is it true that an irreducible polynomial is only divisible by a fixed set of primes finitely many times?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a fixed set of primes $\{ p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_k \} $ is it true that for $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ an irreducible polynomial with $\text{deg}(f) \geq 2$  there are only finitely many solutions $(n, a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k)$ to $f(n) = p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$?

Comment: Not following.  If $f(x)=x^k$ then $f(p_1^m)=p_1^{km}$ for all $m$.

Comment: ^irreducible polynomial in Z[x]

Comment: Ah, missed that.

Comment: @Antosha The question in the title is not the same with the question in the body of the post. The former says "*divisible by*", the latter implies "*divisible by and only by*". Which one did you mean to ask?

Comment: @dxiv the latter, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I can’t help but think that *surely* there’s one classical (which doesn’t have to be “easy”) theorem that covers this… I just don’t know which one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be nonzero with at least two distinct complex roots (that is, $f$ is not of the form $a(x-b)^n$). Let's prove that the statement holds for $f$.

Let $S$ be a finite set of prime numbers, containing all those dividing the leading coefficient of $f$ and the discriminant of $f$. Let $K$ be the number field generated by all the roots of $f$, and let $S_0$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing all those above $S$.

Choose $\alpha,\beta \in K$ two distinct roots of $K$. Then $\alpha,\beta \in O_{K,S_0}$ and, for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $f(n)$ is only divisible by primes of $S$, then $n-\alpha,n-\beta \in O_{K,S_0}^{\times}$. By assumption $\alpha-\beta \in O_{K,S}^{\times}$, so that $n$ produces a solution to the $S_0$-unit equation

$$\frac{n-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha} + \frac{\beta-n}{\beta-\alpha}=1.$$

By the Siegel-Mahler theorem (see eg Hindry-Silverman, *Diophantine Geometry*,  Theorem D.8.1 for a precise enough statement), the $S_0$-unit equation has finitely many solutions in $K$: therefore there are only finitely many such $n$.

(Note: a special case with $f$ a product of rational linear factors and "few enough primes" was the N2 of the IMO Shortlist 2011, with a "similar" proof idea -- except that in this case, we can avoid Siegel-Mahler altogether and elementarily patch the argument)

Comment: Thank you so much!